# NestJS Unit Testing of the Service: Mocking getManager resulting in 'Connection "default" was not found' error

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am currently unit testing my NestJS Service. My entity is called 'User' and I established a basic Service that allows me to interact with a MS SQL server, with GET and POST endpoints established in my Controller.

One of the service methods I am trying to mock is the `deleteV2` function, which you can find below:

```
// service file 
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection, InjectEntityManager, InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection, createConnection, EntityManager, getConnection, getManager, getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import {User} from '../entities/user.entity';


@Injectable()
export class ServiceName {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
              @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection,
              @InjectEntityManager() private manager: EntityManager
              ) {}

  async delete(id: number): Promise<any> {
    return await this.manager.delete(User, id);
  }
  async deleteV2(id: number): Promise<any> {
    return await getManager().delete(User, id);
  }
```

Note that the reason I have imported `EntityManager` AND injected (with `@InjectEntityManager()`) a `manager: EntityManager` into my service is for the simple reason that I wanted some more practice working with different methods (I'm a new intern working with NestJS). The fact that I have the `delete` method defined where I use the injected `manager` and then the `deleteV2` method defined where I use the imported `getManager` is also for the pure reason of practicing unit testing with different ways. And the fact that I'm injecting Repository, Connection, and EntityManager, is also for the same reason.

In my spec.ts unit testing file for the service, I have:

```
// unit testing file for the service

type MockType<T> = { 
    [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<{}>;
};

describe('service tests', () => {
    const mockManagerFactory = jest.fn(() => ({
        delete: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(undefined),
    }))
 
    let service: ServiceName;
    // mock repository and mock connection also defined similarly to mockManager
    let mockManager: MockType<EntityManager>; 

    beforeEach(async () => {     
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ServiceName,
                // tokens for Repository and Connection are also provided along with their respective Factories
                {
                    provide: getEntityManagerToken(),
                    useFactory: mockManagerFactory,
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<ServiceName>(ServiceName);
        // mockRepository and mockConnection also defined but not shown
        mockManager = module.get(getEntityManagerToken());
    });
})
```

Staying on the same spec.ts file, I defined multiple tests. The one that is causing problem is the one that involves `deleteV2` below:

```
// same unit testing file for the service 
         
        // first test
        it('first test', async () => {
            expect(await service.delete(1000)).toEqual(undefined);
            expect(mockManager.delete).toBeCalled();
        });
        
        // second test 
        it('second test', async () => {
            expect(await service.deleteV2(1000)).toEqual(undefined);
            expect(mockManager.delete).toBeCalled();
        })
```

While the first test has no problem running (the first test is associated with `delete` in the service file), the second test (associated with `deleteV2` in the service file) does not pass and results in the following error:

```
● service tests › Service Functions › second test

ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

      at new ConnectionNotFoundError (error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
      at ConnectionManager.Object.<anonymous>.ConnectionManager.get (connection/ConnectionManager.ts:40:19)
      at Object.getManager (index.ts:260:35)
```

Any ideas how to approach this error? It seems as though providing `getEntityManagerToken()` works with the injected `manager` but not with the `getManager` that is imported, since `deleteV2` uses `getManager` while `delete` (which passes the test) uses the imported `manager`

Answer (score 3):

This is where a huge benefit of using dependency injection comes in. `@InjectEntityManager()` just injects the object that (theoretically) already has the connection set up for you, and you can just use the methods without concern about the connection. It makes testing significantly easier (in my opinion). With `getMananger()` you have to worry about TypeORM trying to get the entity manger from the current active connection, which shouldn't be there in tests. You can mock this using `jest` by using something like the following

```js
const deleteMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('typeorm', () => ({
  getManager: () => ({
    delete: deleteMock,
  })
}))
```

This works well enough, but I would avoid calling methods like `getConnection` and `getManager` from TypeORM directly if possible.

Comment: Looks good ,but could you please tell me how to mock @InjectEntityManager()